# Error: "Cannot capture 'word' before it is declared" iOS swift

Tags: swift

I'm writing code for a dictionary app in splitviewcontroller. I set a "Word" class with various entries, which are now not being read by the computer when I try to label them.

import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

```
class Word {
let name: String
let meaning: String
let numberOfTimesTapped: String

init(name: String, meaning: String, numberOfTimesTapped: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.meaning = meaning
    self.numberOfTimesTapped = numberOfTimesTapped
}

}


@IBOutlet weak var WordLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var DescriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var NumberOfTimesTappedLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    func refreshUI() {
        loadViewIfNeeded()
WordLabel.text = word?.name //[THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR: "Cannot capture 'word' before it is declared" ALTHOUGH IT'S BEEN CLEARLY DECLARED BEFORE!!!]
DescriptionLabel.text = word?.meaning
NumberOfTimesTappedLabel.text = word?.numberOfTimesTapped
    }


    var word: Word? {
        didSet {
            refreshUI()

        }
    }
```

Comment: why do you have a function inside `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: Please fix your codeblock and close all the opened curly brackets.

Comment: Please delete this question since it is clearly caused by a simple typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd see it much easier if you were using proper indentation, but you declare `var word` **inside** of `refreshUI`. You need to declare it outside of that so that the scope is accessible inside of `refreshUI`. Also you declare `refreshUI` **inside** of `viewDidLoad`, which is most likely not what you want. A fixed version of this code would be

```
var word: Word? {
    didSet {
        refreshUI()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func refreshUI() {
    loadViewIfNeeded()
    WordLabel.text = word?.name
    DescriptionLabel.text = word?.meaning
    NumberOfTimesTappedLabel.text = word?.numberOfTimesTapped
}
```